# Using both Vuex and emit events

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vuejs2

I have recently started working in VueJS and I have been instructed by one of the lead devs to never combine emit events and vuex store. Basically, if the project will use a store, take all the events/state through the store.

From one point of view I can understand this, but there are a lot scenarios in which emiting an event is so much faster than taking everything through the store.

Is this the best practice by not combining Vuex and emit events?

Comment: When you say 'emit events', do you mean using an event bus or are you just talking about child components emitting events to the parent component?

Comment: I mostly used events from child components but for the sake of discussion we can add event bus as well.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

As a lead developer myself using Vue, this arbitrary rule is simply narrow-minded.

When using Vuex and deciding to use an emit or not, I look at the relationship. If I have a component that only needs to interact with its parent, then I use an emit. It keeps the store cleaner and the relationships clearer. Your lead is not making scalable or maintainable code.

If he/she argues you shouldn't use emits when you have a store, then following that logic, you shouldn't use props ever either. That is equally nonsensical.

Once you start working with applications that have several children down, you'll realize that jamming the store with every variable you'll need just for a few components way down the hierarchy creates a horrible mess of things.

Comment: This is why I wasked the question in the first place. I feel like the store has become messy and will get messier with every single true/false variable that I add. And on top of that store variable, I have to create a mutation and an action and possible a getter for every single thing that I add which will bloat the store/code even more. Thank you for your answer!

Comment: I highly recommend talking to your lead dev about it and getting a thorough explanation for the reasoning. That's a lot of boilerplate just to avoid emits and props. If he's a competent leader, he will at least listen and be open to questions and reconsidering since his rule his anti-pattern.

Comment: The overall reasoning was that this was what the store was made for. My reasoning was that in certain situations it is an overkill.

Comment: I wonder if his programs consist of nothing but global variables. Well, your lead is forcing an objectively anti-pattern approach. Sorry for your situation.

Answer (score 4):

I disagree with your Lead. Vuex should only be used for data that is truly global. Any data/events that are only shared between a component and its child should go through emit/props.

While there can/should be debate about what should use the store vs props and emit, a blanket "always use store" is almost certainly wrong and will lead to a needlessly bloated store.